# I need my report to only show the current record

Tags: ms-access

I asked a question yesterday which was answered and now works. I need to extend the code to modify the report slightly. I have a form called Specification with a field called "SpecID". I have added a button to this form to open a specific report but obviously it opens the report to include all the records in the Specification Form. I want the report to only show one record which would be referenced by the SpecID field and which would be the currently open record in the form. I have tried various ideas based on some of the answers on here but none seem to have worked.

Currently my code is DoCmd.OpenReport Me![Report Name], acViewPreview

I need better brains than mine to tell me what I need to add to this to get the report to only show data from the currently open form which will be referenced by the SpecID field. Im sure it will be simple and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend your code to include a *filter expression*:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport Me![Report Name], acViewPreview, , "[SpecID]=" & Me!SpecID.Value & ""
```

Comment: Sadly whislt it works with previously added records when its a new record it opens with a blank report. My guess is I need to save the form first. I added Do.Cmd.Save acForm, "Specification" to save the Specification Form before opening the report. This does not seem to work.... Apart from a knowledge of VBA, what am I missing...

Comment: Sorry  DoCmd Not Do.Cmd... that would be too obvious

Comment: Yes, that's how. Or you could use: `Me.Dirty = False` to save the record.

Comment: Figured it out with the save record command. all working now. Thanks for your help.